# Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Cannot validate serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerde

Tags: hive, avro, flume-twitter, hive-serde, avro-tools

I am creating a hive table using `avro serde` to store twitter data.

Here's the code-

```
create table tweets
    row format serde
    'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerde'
    stored as inputformat
    'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
    outputformat
    'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
 tblproperties('avro.schema.url'='hdfs://user/itelligence/ee/TwitterDataAvroSchema.avsc');
```

I am getting error-

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. 
Cannot validate serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerde
```

I already tried giving input of avsc file as

```
tblproperties('avro.schema.url'='hdfs:///user/itelligence/ee/TwitterDataAvroSchema.avsc');
tblproperties('avro.schema.url'='file://user/itelligence/schema/TwitterDataAvroSchema.avsc');
```

In both local and hdfs file systems I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The error message states that Hive does not find the SerDe Java class. It does not even bother to read the schema...

Note that "SerDe" has a **capital D** because it stands for Serializer-Deserializer.
So just fix your typo in `AvroSerDe` and try again.

Comment: I tried capital D . but issue was hive SerDe class file was corrupted .